# How to boost up XAML designer in visual studio 2010?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

When i use XAML designer it is so hard and slow to move into the designer and out of it, visual studio stuck for a while when i do that, is there any way to boost up XAML designer and editor?

Ant it is very slow when saving XAML files!

Comment: mine is Intel core i3 540 3GHz, 6GB of ram, 64-bit windows 7 operating system, i think it is ok, and no need to upgrade!!!

Comment: mine is i7 8GB 64bit win 7,still slow depending on generation of designer partial class while save.

Comment: Mine is the same as @DavutGürbüz now, but with an SSD! this is the secret!! it is very nice now.

Comment: Upgraded to 16 GB ram ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy an SSD (Solid State Drive), put your source code and OS on it, and go XAML!

Comment: The same as mine, it is reasonable! I think there is something wrong with your machine, Note: don't use the designer ever, only use XAML editor, use the designer to view your work only!

Comment: SSD solved the save issue, but the design still some slow, but can be Ok for me, maybe because the XAML is not my main work!

Comment: Found a combination which works for me. Before opening XAML in designer, open it in text editor and change all `IsExpanded">True` to `IsExpanded">False`. Then save and open in designer. Open only needed node without expanding others.

Answer (score 4):

That usually means that you might have complex UI, maybe time to break it down into smaller components?

I usually turn off showing XAML View by default: 
`Tools > Options > TextEditor > XAML > Misc`

- Check Always open documents in XAML view
- and uncheck Automatically populate toolbox items.

Comment: It is ok, but saving still very slow!

Comment: there were problems reported with Windows XP and VS. As VS 2010 was designed in WPF and Windows XP had WPF issues, but your box is Windows 7. how about this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/06/22/improving-performance-by-changing-the-visual-experience-vstipenv0017.aspx?

Comment: saving slow ? maybe time to move to Solid State drive :)? a colleague of mine got one and solution takes 20 sec to build compared to 2 min for me.....

Comment: I didn't faced any problems with other file types (non-xaml files)

Comment: Saving of long and complex xaml is also slow for me on SSD drive, not much help in this situation

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem in VS2010 when you save the XAML file there a is partial class same name with XAML class generating.

We can see this class easily by clickin InitializeComponents() as you know. 
But Expression Blend doesn't generate these Class.g.s... files immediately .

I hope In Visual Studio's later versions these will be fixed.

It's similar in Android Development Platform Eclipse there is a "R.class" holds all visual element ids. When you save any xml layout file this class get an update.

These new development approaches has some bad effects for developers I think. 
There must be option such as Ctrl+G+Save ? save and generate :)

If you change any XAML and not save when you click another XAML or CS (unfocus anyway) this slowly behavior still exist.

Beside this if you just save UI without generating , dev.environment can't notify you about existing errors and warnings.

Finally It steals too much time from developers. ,

Need to be solved.

*I was preparing  to ask this question I see it here.Thanks for asking.*

Answer (score 0):

The XAML editor in Visual Studio 2010 (though better than it used to be) still has performance issues.  If available, I would recommend using [Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/Blend_Overview.aspx) and Visual Studio side-by-side during development.  They integrate well and Blend is meant for handling XAML.  You could also try [Kaxaml](http://kaxaml.com/) which is useful is some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use generic text editor with xaml, greatly boosts up performance, but you loose WYSIWYG window.

To open with generic, just right click on xaml file -> open with -> Source code (text) editor and make it default if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a Xaml file in the Solution Explorer and select the XML (Text) Editor - then Click Set as Default.

Obviously I don't get the UI preview any more, but you do still get autocomplete in the xml editor and it is a night and day difference in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple Editor to do your massive modification, then switch back to Visual Studio. compile and Fix your code if necessary.

I use notepad++ that you can open selecting "Open With..." entry from the contextual menu and then adding to the list of your application.

This tips works well when I had to modified an existing large file.

Answer (score 0):

After months of performance issues.. clear your temp directory. Mine had swollen to 100GB and 10's of thousands of files. Unless you're diligent this dir may not have been cleaned in a while:

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp

ie.

C:\Users{currentuser}\AppData\Local\Temp

The WPF XAML editor performs as it should now.

Answer (score -1):

Please see: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/521394/xaml-editor-causes-hang-freeze-of-visual-studio-2010

Disabling hardware acceleration solved the problem for me.

UPDATE:

the link above is broken... you may try this post http://www.japf.fr/2011/03/visual-studio-2010-and-hw-acceleration-on-windows-xp/