# Visual Studio 2012 XAML designer process eating up memory

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2012

I have just started using Visual studio 2012 and the issue with it is the designer process and the devenv.exe are eating up more than one gigs of memory.  question here is the XAML designer process XDesProc.exe never cleans up the memory and loads a lot of designers at once. Don't know anybody notice it because of having high memory. but i have 4 Gigs RAM it just bumps up and uses the whole in a lot. I have also a screenshot which shows like 200 Megs used by just designer.

[image: Task Manager]

**Edited:** it gets worst when i do a build and not in debug mode in release mode it gets stuck and after few minutes application comes up.
[image]

Comment: VS2k10 is really no different, all of my instances are >400mb RAM after startup. What is your question/aim/purpose exactly?

Comment: [Try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10601435/1834662). Keep number of open files lesser in Editor tabs. If you can afford to, then check in your View, VM class ctor's if in designer mode and just return to not process too much stuff in the background. Finally setup a 64bit Build config and switch to it even if on a x86 machine(not sure if you can have a 64bit build config on a x86 machine). VS designer does not work in 64bit so that might trim off more ide consumption.

Comment: oh check and disable any addin's you do not absolutely need. Finally put in an order for some RAM or a better machine all-together

Comment: I don't use addin's and its a fresh install with update 2. I have updated it with worst scenario that happens once i build

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do abt this tbh. I've seen some CI machine's tht are x86 with 4gb ram and not just in a WPF project even with something like C++ it takes insanely longer to build stuff. Release mode does some further code optimizations like LTCG in c++. I'd bet there are similar stuff in a wpf project too for release optimisations that take longer compared to debug.

Comment: I found a workaround for that but thats not a good thing right click and set default to xaml file to open with `Source editor` instead of opening it into `Automatic XAML editor`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yeah, it's the XAML files! Here's a couple of tips:

If you are not addicted to `Design` view (I never use it), I would open `XAML` files as `txt` files so that they don't have to compile - that should help.

```
Right-Click on the .xaml file in Solution Explorer
Open with.. 
Select Source Code (Text) Editor
Click <Set as Default> button so  you don't have to do it again.
Click <OK> button
```

When VisualStudio really pisses me off with it's XAML slowness. I switch to `Kaxaml`. It's free and super light-weight.

I also keep the Windows Task Manager open and periodically kill of XDesProc.exe's (MS VisualStudio XAML UI Design processes) when they popup. Probably should just write a powershell script or an app that kills those.. (should be pretty simple, create a timer, and on elapsed find and kill)

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but nevertheless this might be useful for some people out there; I found ["Kill the WPF Designer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b7009e69-5e84-4221-bce2-5f0240a70464)" extension, using which you can kill the XDesProc from within visual studio.

[Edit] You could also go to Options->XAML Designer and uncheck Enable XAML Designer.

Comment: This extension is on demand. Would not be a good use-case for most of the people.

Comment: Even with the "Source Code (Text) Editor" VS still started the XDesProc.exe process. I just renamed the file from "XDesProc.exe" to "XDesProc.exe.useless" and it has not since started it.